Add btree_gin index via rails migration
If I have this migration file in ruby
class AddBtreeGinIndex < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  disable_ddl_transaction!

  def change
    enable_extension 'btree_gin'

    add_index :table_name, [:column_A, :column_B, :column_C, :column_D_with_array_of_big_int],
              name: 'sample_btree_gin_index', algorithm: :concurrently, using: :gin
  end

end
Can I say it create the index using btree_gin? Since the code states as a gin, how do I ensure that index is using btree_gin, not ordinary gin index?
I'm using Rails 6.1.7.8
ruby 3.0.1p64 (2021-04-05 revision 0fb782ee38) [arm64-darwin21]
Database:
postgres (PostgreSQL) 14.13 (Homebrew)
When I run migration it says:
== 20241029093107 AddBtreeGinIndex: migrating ===============
  -- enable_extension("btree_gin")
-> 0.0060s
-- add_index(:table_name, [:column_A, :column_B, :column_C, :column_D_with_array_of_big_int], {:name=>"sample_btree_gin_index", :algorithm=>:concurrently, :using=>:gin})
-> 0.0162s
== 20241029093107 AddBtreeGinIndex: migrated (0.0224s) ======

If I check this query
select * from pg_extension;

I get this row
235562  btree_gin   10  2200    true    1.3 NULL    NULL


I already run the migration and it says:
== 20241029093107 AddBtreeGinIndex: migrating ===============
  -- enable_extension("btree_gin")
-> 0.0060s
-- add_index(:table_name, [:column_A, :column_B, :column_C, :column_D_with_array_of_big_int], {:name=>"sample_btree_gin_index", :algorithm=>:concurrently, :using=>:gin})
-> 0.0162s
== 20241029093107 AddBtreeGinIndex: migrated (0.0224s) ======


Look at the index in the database and see what was actually created.

If I check the index from
select * from pg_catalog.pg_indexes
I see my indexname in indexdef column:
CREATE INDEX table_name ON public.table_name USING gin (column_A, column_B, column_C, column_D_with_array_of_big_int)

If I check from Dbeaver and click the index, the access method only states as gin

btree_gin allows the creation of GIN indexes on int, float, varchar, timestamp, etc columns. Assuming on the columns in your index is not a json column the index is using btree_gin or you would have received an error on creation.

Yes, it is not a json column, but bigint[] in the last column

While you can add gin indexes to array columns it's like putting racing wheels on a Yugo.
